# Why does "return Nothing" return Nothing?

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

"return a" is supposed to wrap a in the context of some Monad:

```
*Main> :i return
class Applicative m => Monad (m :: * -> *) where
  ...
  return :: a -> m a
  ...
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

If I ask GHCI what the type of "return Nothing" is, it conforms to that:

```
*Main> :t return Nothing
return Nothing :: Monad m => m (Maybe a)
```

But if I evaluate it, I see no outer Monad, just the inner Maybe:

```
*Main>  return Nothing
Nothing
```

Comment: GHCi defaults to the IO monad if you don't specify one. It's just printing the contents of an `IO (Maybe a)`

Comment: @4castle To slightly misquote shachaf: An `IO (Maybe a)` contains a `Maybe a` in the same way that `/bin/ls` contains a list of files. This might sound a bit pedantic, but it isn't printing the contents of `IO (Maybe a)`. It is running an `IO (Maybe a)` and then printing the results of that. The distinction can be important.

Comment: @DavidYoung I don't personally find the distinction to be important, because it's the IO monad's job to know the internal representation of the value. For reasoning purposes, I usually think of all monads as containers (whether they actually contain the value or not).

Comment: @4castle I see your point, but still think we should avoid talking about “`IO a` containing an `a` value”. Especially beginners coming from procedural/OO languages tend to think that `IO String` actually just contains one `String` object (which the type system waywardly prevents them from properly accessing). But that's just wrong – you can only say an `IO String` value contains – abstractly – _all_ possible results that running the `IO` action could possibly yield, however not any one particular result. I really like the `/bin/ls` analogy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When GHCi goes to print a value, it tries two different things. First, it tries to unify the type with `IO a` for some `a`. If it can do that then it executes the IO action and tries to print the result. If it can't do that, it tries to print the given value. In your case, `Monad m => m (Maybe a)` can be unified with `IO (Maybe a)`.

Reviewing this GHCi session might help:

```
Prelude> return Nothing
Nothing
Prelude> return Nothing :: IO (Maybe a)
Nothing
Prelude> return Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe a)
Just Nothing
Prelude> Nothing
Nothing
```