# How to get Sum {getSum = 0}?

Tags: haskell

I have following instances implementations:

```
newtype Constant a b =
  Constant { getConstant :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

type TI a = Constant a

instance Functor (Constant a) where
  fmap _ (Constant a) = Constant a

instance Foldable (Constant a) where
  foldMap _ _ = mempty
```

and then I tried following:

```
*ExerciseTraversable Data.Monoid> foldMap id (Constant (Sum 34))
()
```

I do expect `Sum {getSum = 0}` instead of `()`. How to get `Sum {getSum = 0}` as the result?

Comment: (Out of curiosity, is `Constant` related to the built-in `Const` functor https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.2/base-4.9.1.0/Control-Applicative.html#t:Const?)

Comment: No no, it is just a exercise of the book.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria The two types work in exactly the same way (only the names are different).

Comment: @DavidYoung I was just making sure the OP wasn't reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess GHCi is choosing `foldMap id (Constant (Sum 34)) :: IO ()`, which incidentally type checks because `Constant (Sum 34) :: Constant (Sum Int) b` for any `b`, including `b ~ IO ()`.

Disambiguate the type, so that GHCi does not default it for you:

```
foldMap id (Constant (Sum 34)) :: Sum Int
-- or
foldMap id (Constant (Sum 34) :: Constant (Sum Int) (Sum Int))
```

By the way, `foldMap id (Constant "hello" :: Constant String (Sum Int))` should also work -- there's no relation between the content of `Constant` and its phantom index.

Comment: Also, if you run `:t foldMap id (Constant (Sum 34))`, you see that its type is `Monoid m => m`, so GHCi must be doing defaulting.

Comment: Is it `IO ()` or just `()`?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs That's a tricky question... `()` has a `Monoid` instance and `IO` has `instance Monoid a => Monoid (IO a)`. I think I saw a way to "trick" GHCi into showing what type it is defaulting to in situations like this, but I don't quite remember it (also, this was a couple years back, so it might not work on newer GHCis).

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I think GHCi would pick `IO ()` before `()` ? Not completely sure, though. Perhaps it's `()` after all.

Comment: what is a phantom index?

Comment: @zero_coding Some type parameter as `b` which is not used in the definition. E.g. `data T a = C` uses the phantom `a`.

Comment: @DavidYoung Yeah, it turns out I should have just read my own answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558914/why-does-return-nothing-return-nothing/45558972#45558972